# Installing dependcies for running files in AWS Codebuilder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, installation, aws-codebuild, aws-codestar

I am trying to run test files on AWS codebuilder pulling from a CodeCommit but the files have many dependencies that need to be installed.  Many of them are included in Anaconda but I am worried that this will slow down the build speed considerably if I install anaconda every time because of the size of anaconda.  Is there a way to efficiently install a list of dependencies or do I have to manually do it every time in the install portion of the buildspec? or is there a way that I could install the dependencies once rather than every time I build.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own Docker image containing your dependencies (e.g., Anaconda) pre-installed. This Docker image can then be referenced [when creating a project](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/create-project.html).

The AWS DevOps blog has a [step by step example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments/) of building a custom Docker environment for CodeBuild.